# как сделать код более производительным и аккуратным

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Больше интересуют map sort и можно ли добавить сюда мемоизацию

```js
const Projects = ( { projects, match, newProjectsId } ) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation ();


  projects.map ( project =>
    newProjectsId.includes ( project.projectId ) ?
      project.color = 'true'
      :
      project.color = 'false' );

  projects.sort ( ( a ) => a.color === 'true'  ? -1 : 1 );


  return (
    <ProjectsContainer>
      <Switch>

        <Route exact path={ `${ match.path }` } render={ () =>
          <>
            <TitleMd>{ t ( 'projectsPage.projects' ) }</TitleMd>
            <ProjectsItemsWrapper>
              { projects && projects.map (
                ( project, idx ) =>
                  <Fragment key={ idx }>
                    <ProjectCard projectData={ project } />
                  </Fragment>
              ) }
            </ProjectsItemsWrapper>
          </>
        } />

        <Route exact path={ `${ match.path }/:projectKey` } component={ ProjectPage } />
      </Switch>
    </ProjectsContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый projects.map, можно убрать, сделать сразу сортировку.

```
projects.sort ( ( project ) => newProjectsId.includes ( project.projectId ) ? -1 :1);
```